# Finite connected groups over a perfect field of characteristic p

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hopf-algebras, algebraic-groups, characteristic-p

In 14.4 of "Introduction to Affine Group Schemes" it is proved (!) that if $A$ represents a finite connected group scheme over a perfect field $k$ of characteristic $p$ then $A$ has the form $k[X_{1}, X_{2}, ..., X_{n}] / (X_{1}^{p^{e_{1}}}, ...., X_{n}^{p^{e_{n}}})$. But what about $\mu_{p} = k[X]/(X^{p}-1)$? It is connected but not isomorphic to $k[X]/(X^{p})$ as $k$-groups. They are isomorphic as $k$-schemes.
Does this theorem mean " ...... $A$ has the form $k[X_{1}, X_{2}, ..., X_{n}] / (X_{1}^{p^{e_{1}}}, ...., X_{n}^{p^{e_{n}}})$ up to isomorphism of $k$-schemes"?

Comment: The book surely has an author?

Comment: Is this book?
http://books.google.com.ar/books?id=l0DgAIx_djoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Waterhouse+schemes&hl=en&ei=ARLmTt-zCeX50gGx57WDAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Waterhouse%20schemes&f=false

Comment: $A$ is an algebra, not a scheme. The statement means the only thing it can possibly mean, that $A$ is of that form as an algebra.

Comment: The book's theorem in (14.4) states "Let A represent a finite connected group scheme ...". So A should not only be an algebra but a Hopf algebra. Moreover in the proof is used/phrased  that A is a Hopf algebra. In my opinion it's not that clear, that the proof really works well. As far as I can see, the critical point is the height 1 case where Waterhouse refers to (11.4), but (11.4) doesn't reflect the Hopf algebra structure. 

Comment: Possibly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16000/question-regarding-waterhouse-affine-group-schemes

Comment: Thanks,
I mean Spec$A$ by saying that $A$ is a scheme. Since the categeory of affine $k$-groups are anti-equivalent to category of $k$-Hopf algebras I say like this. The author is Waterhouse. But this statement exists in many lecture notes that I can't list them now. I think what Ralph says is true, because the the critical part of the proof is the case height=1. So I think it should be understood from the theorem that " ...... A has the form $k[X_{1}, X_{2}, ..., X_{n}] / (X_{1}^{p^{e_{1}}}, ...., X_{n}^{p^{e_{n}}})$ as a $k$-algebra (not as a $k$-Hopf algebra)".


Comment: @Angelo: The isomorphism could be an algebra isomorphism, or a Hopf algebra isomorphism. The correct statement is that there is an algebra isomorphism between $A$ and $k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/(X_1^{p^{e_1}},\ldots)$. As Hopf algebras, the classification is more complicated (is there a classification???).

Comment: To André: what I am saying is that, since one interpretation is obviously wrong, as the OP knows, the other must be the right one. As to a classification of finite connected group schemes, if it possible at all, it will be certainly enormously complicated.

Comment: To Andre: As I know there is not any classification for connected group schemes (and so for their representing Hopf-algebras). In "p-divisible groups", Tate proves an equivalence between the category of connected $p$-divisible groups and the category of divisible formal Lie groups. Maybe this may help you.

Comment: @Angelo: all that’s needed is a Dieudonné theory extended from the commutative theory to noncommutative finite groupschemes. If properly done, it would classify finite $p$-groups of the kind we learned about as kids, so what you say is spot-on.

Answer (score 2):

Others can do this much better than I, but here's what's happening: to describe a group scheme of any kind, you need to talk about not only the underlying space, but also the law of composition on the group. In this case, the kernel of $[p]$ in the muliplicative group, you describe the law of composition by writing down the the comultiplication on the affine ring $k[X]/(X^p)$. This is simply $X\mapsto 1 \otimes X + X \otimes 1 + X \otimes X$.

Comment: So $\alpha_p$ and $\mu_p$ have the same underlying space, so the same affine ring, but different comultiplications.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $x\mapsto x\otimes x$ rather?

Comment: @darij: no, not if the ring is $k[X]/(X^p)$. Yes, if the ring is $k[X]/(X^p-1)$.

Comment: How is this an answer ? The starting point of the OP is exactly what you describe, namely that a group scheme is classified by a Hopf algebra and not just by its coordinate algebra. As such it turned out that in the book's theorem the isomorphism has to be understood as an isomorphism of algebras. 

Comment: @Lubin: ah, my stupid.

Comment: @Ralph, the text only says something about the underlying space of a connected finite groupscheme. It was OP’s misunderstanding to think that isomorphic affine rings must give isomorphic groupschemes. The missing ingredient is the comultiplication, which OP never mentioned.

Comment: @Lubin: The OP takes two group schemes, one with corresponding Hopf algebra $k[X]/(X^p)$ and one with $k[X]/(X^p-1)$ and says they are "
not isomorphic ... as k-groups. They are isomorphic as k-schemes". 
There is not one phrase in the text that supposes isomorphic rings must give isomorphic group-schemes. The actual problem was that Waterhouse doesn't specify what kind of isomorphism is given. 

Comment: It looks like the real problem is that both Ralph and A.E. used the term "Hopf algebra" when describing an object, but only specified the algebra structure.  At any rate, the answer to the question is "yes".

Comment: Thanks to everyone,
In fact what Ralph says is true. I was knowing that these two objects do not give the same group scheme. I just wanted to be sure about author's style. Because there are many important results about affine group schemes in that book and so one may expect those results to be something about Hopf algebra structures. So any beginner in this subject like me may have confusion while studying on that book. It means that I (and any reader of that book) must pay attention to this.